# Why is my CSS lost when auto zoom kicks-in on cell phone?

Tags: css

I am creating my first mobile-first design. I have started with a log-in page.
Media queries are doing their job. However, when an input gets focus and the auto zoom kicks-in on the cell phone, all styling is lost.

For two days, on and off, I have searched the web for what I thought would be an easy find. "Why is CSS lost on auto zoom?"  But, nothing. (Perhaps others never had this issue?). I've tried working with different breakpoints, thinking that may be the issue. But, nothing. It has become a great source of frustration because I am unable to go forward until I get this resolved.

Could anyone educate me on this?

Comment: Beats us. Post some code

Comment: It's more likely that you have styles effecting the element _on focus_ rather than when the browser is zoomed.

Comment: Ok. It's too much code to post. But if it would serve the purpose, my page opens-up at well-versed.org. When using an Android cell phone device in portrait view, it looks as desired. But when you tap on an input (causing auto zoom to kick-in), my fonts, borders and other styling disappears. There is nothing I have found that explains why this is happening. Please be kind. I am a 54-year old who has taken up web design as  a hobby. It is not a profession. If there is something specific code-wise you need to see, I'd be happy to post it.

Answer (score 0):

When combining media queries, it is important to separate them with a comma as shown below.

`@media only screen and (max-width: 600px), and (orientation: portrait) {...`

Otherwise, your css will be lost when auto zoom kicks-in.